# Strange numerical error when using Java Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm with large numbers?

Tags: java, algorithm, memory, numerical-methods

I'm experiencing the strangest problem and have been having a terrible time debugging it. I thought I'd post it here to get any opinions.

```
public static void sieve(int limit) {

    for (int i = 2; i < limit; i ++) {

        if (mPrimes[i] == true) {

            for (int j = i*i; ((j < limit) && (j > 0)); j += i) {
                mPrimes[j] = false;
            }

        }

    }

}
```

(assume mPrimes are all initially true)

Here's the catch:

When I run this program with limits of 10, 100, 1000, 10000, and even 100000, it reports counting the correct number of primes below the given number, as cross-referenced with this page: http://primes.utm.edu/howmany.shtml

However, when I run with an argument of 1000000 (one million), I get a result that is exactly 7 away from the correct value (it reports 78491 instead of 78498).

Furthermore, All the other methods of prime-counting I've implemented in this program report the correct value.

And here's the real catch: If I replace

```
i*i
```

with

```
i+i
```

As to start "crossing out" directly from the seed value, instead of starting from the square (which is what my professor had done in his sample code), it works.

This leaves me only to assume that something strange is happening with the square when i is very large.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try using long instead of int? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: there is no reason to incude `j > 0` in your second for statement. Since j is the square of i, which is always greater than 0, j is also always greater than 0.

Comment: Yes, that was actually a previous fix because of the same error (i*i overflowing and creating -2^31 which still passed the < limit test). I can remove that now that I've fixed the problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its an overflow error. 1,000,000 * 1,000,000 needs more bits than an int (2**32 - 1) can accommodate.  You need to use a long (2**64 -1).

Answer (score 1):

There is no point to cross any numbers if `i*i` exceeds a limit. So instead of going long integers, just initialize a variable `strike_limit` to be a ceiling of `sqrt(i)`, and do not even try entering the strike-out loop if `i` exceeds that limit. Sorry I do not know Java well enough to write code in it, but that should be something to the effect of

int strike_limit = (int) (sqrt ((double)limit) + 0.5);

```
    if (mPrimes[i] && i < strike_limit) {
        for (int j = i*i; j < limit; j += i) {
            mPrimes[j] = false;
        }
    }
```

This guarantees you from overflow when calculating i². Be careful to analyze corner cases.

Answer (score 0):

Also, to avoid overflow, outer cycle can be like this: `for (int i = 2; i*i < limit; i++)`, and it will be even faster (cause any non-prime number under `limit` must have at least one prime divisor under `sqrt(limit)`)

Answer (score 0):

Variable *i* is initially 2 and increases at each step, so it is always positive. Variable *j* is initially *i* × *i*, which is positive, and increases by the positive number *i* at each step, so *j* is always positive. Why do you test *j* > 0 in the inner loop?